# Problems when scraping a website with login form with python

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler

### The problem

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to scrape a website with a login at the beginning, which is http://gaonnuri.ksain.net/xe/login this site.

The internet tells you that you should use `post` to enter your password and username, but it doesn't work like its supposed to.

So the way I did it was: I first created a payload with my username and password (the id and password in the code is fake)
and then posted the in the website.

The payload name `user_id` and `password` came from the `html name` of the login form, like many sites say it should.

### This is my code

```
import requests

session=requests.Session()

payload = {
    'user_id': 'myusername',
    'password': 'mypassword'
}


s = session.post('http://gaonnuri.ksain.net/xe/login', data=payload)

s = session.get('http://gaonnuri.ksain.net/xe/?mid=home')
print(s.text)
```

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: You can monitor the API call made for logging in using the Network Tab of Chrome/Firefox(Press F12) and try to replicate the same in your code.

Comment: Can you explain how to find the api called? there's loads of data being called as I log in. And can you also explain how to recreate it in my code? I'm new to all this.